# Change person's presence state using vLine API

Tags: vline

How do I change a person's status (setPresenceState) after the user accepts a call?
I need to set the state to "busy" for the person.

I think I can set the presence to busy when the "enterState:active" event fires, but how exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In our documentation, we say that we automatically set the presence state to 'busy', when on a call, but looking through our code, it looks like we're currently not doing that. I'll fix that, but in the meantime I'll give an example of how you can do this yourself (in case you wanted to have some other behavior).

The general idea is to set the presence state to busy when the [`vline.MediaSession`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaSession) goes into the [`active`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaStates#ACTIVE) state. In this example, `client` is assumed to be the logged-in [`vline.Client`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Client) and `session` is assumed to be the [`vline.Session`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Session) returned after logging in.

```js
client.on('add:mediaSession', function(event) {
  var mediaSession = event.target;
  mediaSession.on('enterState:active', function() {
    session.setPresence('busy');
  }, this);
  mediaSession.on('enterState:closed', function() {
    session.setPresence('online');
  }, this);
}, this);
```

Answer (score -1):

The PresenceStates "busy" don't work, anything u want to do..
I use the "do_not_disturb" PresenceStates, instead of, and reset the state of "do_not_disturb" , even if the media session is 'disconnected' or broke by client or person.

You get it?

add this code instead of :

//----------------------------------------------------------------

```
client.on('add:mediaSession', function(event) {
var mediaSession = event.target;
mediaSession.on('enterState:active', function() {
session.setPresence('do_not_disturb');
}, this);
mediaSession.on('enterState:closed', function() {
session.setPresence('online');
}, this);
mediaSession.on('enterState:outgoing', function() {
session.setPresence('do_not_disturb');
}, this);
mediaSession.on('enterState:incoming', function() {
session.setPresence('do_not_disturb');
}, this);
mediaSession.on('enterState:disconnected', function() {
session.setPresence('online');
}, this);
}, this);
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------

To reset  the state of 'do_not_disturb', what event happen, and even if client or person, have broke the session, just add this code after :

// fetch person object associated with username:
session.getPerson(userId).done(function(person) {

```
session.setPresence('online');
```

( vline.MediaSession is assumed to be into the active state. 
session is assumed to be the vline.Session returned after logging in.)

Answer (score -1):

All will work fine, and when  u send a videocall, nobody can send a other video call